# Cakephp 3.0 Unit testing Issue

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When i execute the plugins/SamplePlugin test cases, it executing perfect except the controller functions which are related to urls.
The test case function like

```
public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->get('/sample-plugin /mycontroller/index');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
```

when i execute the above testcase the exception

```
There was 1 error:

1) SamplePlugin\Test\TestCase\Controller\MyControllerTest::test
Index
include(D:\xampp\htdocs\EATZ_V2_3.X\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\tests\test_app\config\routes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Router.php:974
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Router.php:974
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Router.php:547
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:451
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:392
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:312
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase.php:233
D:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\plugins\SamplePlugin\tests\TestCase\Controller\MyControllerTest.php:29
D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129

FAILURES!
Tests: 30, Assertions: 42, Errors: 1.
```

please resove the issue.thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please do not create duplicates, especially not using multiple accounts, that is considered rather rude, and people are even more unlikely to help. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34741930/1392379 That bein said, there is not enough information here to help you. Please add some more context, like your plugins phpunit configuration, its test bootstrap, the command you are using to run the test, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the routes.php file is missing in the folder config. Refer to the [CakePHP 3 Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) to create a meaningful routes.php.